# How can I properly represent paramagnetic materials in DFT calculations?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-espresso, magnetism

I have seen specific ways of constructing input files for

- [Anti-ferromagnetic materials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/how-to-model-an-anti-ferromagnetic-crystal-in-quantum-espresso-properly)
- [Ferromagnetic materials](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/is-the-final-magnetic-moment-in-the-materials-project-repository-same-as-the).

**How can I represent a paramagnetic material in plane wave DFT codes like Quantum ESPRESSO. Do we assign opposite moments with different magnitudes? Or we do we assume the material to be Non-magnetic?**

Answer (score 5):

Paramagnetic materials have fluctuating magnetic moments that cannot be described using density functional theory. They can be properly described using, for example, dynamical mean-field theory.

Having said this, a typical approach to model paramagnetism in DFT is to build a large supercell of the material and to place randomly oriented magnetic moments on each atom. I have never explored these calculations in detail, so others may be able to comment on the merits of this approximation.

Comment: Thank you, So is it safe to do a non spin polarized calculation in order to study electronic properties ?

Comment: @Atom is it a DFT calculation? Kohn-Sham DFT practically assumes absolute zero temperature, so spin-polarized calculations only make sense for magnets (FM, AFM etc)

Comment: @Xivi76 That makes sense! Thank you! I'm pretty new to DFT and solid state physics, thats why

Comment: @ATOM it is not true to replace paramagnetic with non magnetic, for example in case of FCC iron, lattice parameter of non-magnetic iron is 3.45 while experimental results is far off

Comment: @pranavkumar So how should I proceed?/

Comment: @Atom  for collinear calculation you can use SQS structure of binary system. Put A as upspin and B as low spin and constrain net spin over cell to be zero